# Finding the date of the next day-python

Tags: python

I need to find the date of the next day but without the datetime module

For example, First I have a function that take a date in parameter and I need to validate the date format via a input if the date format is right I display the date of the next day if the day format is wrong I simply display a message "it's not the good date format"

```
 def tomorrow(date : str) -> str:
    
    
    format='AAAA-M-J'  
    
    if begin == 'YES':
        
        year = int(input('Chose a year:'))
        month = int(input('Chose a month:'))
        day = int(input('Chose a day:'))


        if month == 12 and day == 31:
            
            year = year=+1
            month = month=+1
            day = day=+1
            date = str(f'{year}-{month}-{day}')
            if len(date) == len(format):
                return print('next date:' + date)
            
        elif day == 30 and month%2 != 0 or day == 31 and month%2 == 0:
            
            month = month=+1
            day = day=+1
            date = str(f'{year}-{month}-{day}')
            if len(date) == len(format):
                return print('next date:' + date)
            
        elif day < 30 or 31:
            
            day = day=+1
            date = str(f'{year}-{month}-{day}')
            if len(date) == len(format):
                return print('next date:' + date)
        else:
            return print('Not a good date format')
                    
            
    else:
        return print('NO')
        

date = print('date')

begin = str(input('type YES or NO'))
  


print(tomorrow(date))
```

nothing is displayed at the end

What's wrong ?

Comment: Note that the `print` function always returns `None`, regardless of what you ask it to print.

Comment: There are too many issues with this program to address without completely rewriting it - your logic for finding the next day is wrong, your comparison to the length of `format` is incorrect, the logic in more than one of your `if` loop steps is short-circuited... please work on this some more and come back when you have one, *specific* issue. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) for more context.

Comment: I've removed the "return print" and just put print('next date' + date) and return date apart

Comment: But how ? Idk I've already rewrited it 3 times and I thought it was not good but like ok and a little change could have make it work ?

Comment: I don't understand why the `tomorrow` function takes the parameter `date`, which is reassigned inside.

Comment: `year = year=+1` is equivalent to `year = 1`. Will this be what you want?

Comment: ok ok so it's not =+1 but +=1 right ?

Comment: Honestly Idk either it was to put something inside just that

Comment: It returns "None" for date 2022-11-11 and date 2022-12-31 The only one I have tested but it returns the date for 2022-4-4 -> 2022-4-5

Comment: I feel like only the statement for day works but not the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your function doesn't seem to need the `date` parameter, it is reassigned inside the function
2. The `print` function returns `None`, so your function `tomorrow` will always return None.
3. `year = year=+1` is equivalent to `year = 1`, you need to determine if this is what you want.
4. There is a problem with the way to determine whether the time string is in the correct format, such as `len("2021-10-21") != len("AAAA-M-J")`.

The above is the existing problem, I have made the modification below.

Is the format of the time string using regular matching([`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re)) correct, and simplify part of the code.

> `\d`
> For Unicode (str) patterns:
> Matches any Unicode decimal digit (that is, any character in Unicode character category [Nd]). This includes [0-9], and also many other digit characters. If the ASCII flag is used only [0-9] is matched.
>
> `{m,n}`
> Causes the resulting RE to match from m to n repetitions of the preceding RE, attempting to match as many repetitions as possible. For example, a{3,5} will match from 3 to 5 'a' characters. Omitting m specifies a lower bound of zero, and omitting n specifies an infinite upper bound. As an example, a{4,}b will match 'aaaab' or a thousand 'a' characters followed by a 'b', but not 'aaab'. The comma may not be omitted or the modifier would be confused with the previously described form.

`\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}`

> This regular expression means a string that matches four numbers and one or two numbers one or two numbers, and is concatenated using `-`. For example: `2021-1-1`, `2021-12-29`.

```py
import re

date_rule = re.compile(r"\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}")


def tomorrow(begin) -> str:
    if begin == 'YES':

        year = int(input('Chose a year:'))
        month = int(input('Chose a month:'))
        day = int(input('Chose a day:'))

        # Determine if it is the last day of the year.
        if month == 12 and day == 31:
            year += 1
            month = 1
            day = 1

        # Determine if it is the last day of the month.
        elif day == 30 and month % 2 != 0 or day == 31 and month % 2 == 0:
            month += 1
            day = 1

        # In other cases, that is, it is not the last day of the year or month, the number of days is incremented by 1.
        else:
            day += 1

        date = f'{year}-{month}-{day}'
        # If it can match successfully, it means that the format is correct.
        if date_rule.match(date):
            return 'next date:' + date
        else:
            return 'Not a good date format'

    else:
        return 'NO'


print('date')
begin = input('type YES or NO')

print(tomorrow(begin))
```

Comment: It works Thanks

Comment: @n004rp I added some clarification to my answer.